# knockout mapping: combining two objects into one

Tags: knockout.js

I have json coming from server. It contains something like array (`Schedule`), but each `Schedule` element consists of two other objects.

Each `Schedule` element is like this:

```
{"Schedule":[
    {"InputItem": {"Id" : "1231", "Name": "TempName"}, 
     "OutputItem": {"CalcId" : "a1231", "CalcName": "CakcTempName"}
    },
    ...
]};
```

So, in knockout I am having view model that accepts jsonData (as described above):

```
var viewModel = function(jsonData) {
     var self = this;

     var customMapping = {
         //'Schedule': {
         // 
         // }
     };
     ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData, customMapping, self);
};
```

As a result I am getting self.Schedule array that contains `InputItem` and `CalculatedItem`.
However, I need to create such a custom mapping that will combine `InputItem` and `CalculatedItem` into one object, for example, `ScheduleItem`, so that after mapping I would not have `InputItem` and `CalculatedItem`, but only one `ScheduleItem`.

Is it possible?

P.S. The reason why I need this is because it would be much more easier to display Schedule array within grid. Half of grid are InputItems, but half of grid is CalculatedItems. On UI I do not need seperation of those items. 
I can solve the issue also changing my server side models, but here I am asking about KO part.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation on the mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).  The section "Customizing object construction using 'create'" explains how you can define your own logic to control creation of the mapped data.  This would allow you to use a simple jQuery map to perform a projection into the object structure you need.